# Getting a 403 when trying to call a websocket

Tags: websocket, aws-api-gateway

Hey I have a web socket deployed to AWS API gateway with a custom domain and lambda's backing it. I keep getting this error in web console when trying to interact with it through my angular app:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://customDomain/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403
```

I am not seeing anything in logs for API Gateway like anything is trying to hit it, and no function invocations on the lambda side.

I have a deployment for the gateway and best I can tell everything is setup correct. I am trying to move this apigateway from a shared legacy AWS account into a new one using the AWS-CDK so I can confirm from the code level that the setup should be correct.

Comment: All I could think of so far: Does the new server enforce an Origin where the old one didn't? Is it listening on ws: or wss:? If wss, is the server certificate valid and acceptable without user interaction?

Comment: yeah so it does when I use the https connection URL show a {"message":"Forbidden"} but the cert is correct, also confirmed its wss

Comment: ok I test here on this site I get this error:

WebSocket connection to wss://customdomain:443 failed: com.dkfqs.tools.websocket.WebSocketClientConnectException: Invalid HTTP status code received: 403, expected value = 101

and

Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: https://customdomain
Sec-WebSocket-Key: wCzbbZzYTGcfW5ln79+R9w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Failed at Verify HTTP Upgrade Response

Comment: You would almost think there is a web server listening on port 443 and not a websocket server. No, I don't know what's wrong. Have you got another tool / bit of Javascript to try to make a connection to customdomain:443? What does it say when you try to connect to http(s)://customdomain:443 with a browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error here was caused by the API gateway needing to be deployed. After adding the custom domain, I created a new deployment for the stage that was assigned to the custom domain.

When using CDK, you can also set the stage to auto deploy on changes by setting `autoDeploy: true` in your `CfnStage` definition. This was what I ultimately did.

Comment: i'm also having a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947938/403-forbidden-when-aws-websocket-api-gateway-try-to-serve-through-cloudfront) issue. except i created the api gateway using serverless framework and cretaed the origins and behaviours manually.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jared's answer (which I'm grateful for as I was stumped for days) this is an example of what it would look like in your code if using `WebSocketStage` from `@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha`:

```
new WebSocketStage(scope, 'WebSocketStage', {
    webSocketApi,
    stageName: 'your-env-name',
    autoDeploy: true,
});
```