# 403 Forbidden when AWS Websocket Api Gateway try to serve through Cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, http-status-code-403

I have created a Websocket API using AWS's websocket API gateway. After creating the api i got the endpoint like

`wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev`

I could use this directly and invoke the `$connect` lambda without any issue

Now I wanted this to serve via cloudfront.

I already have a distribution which has Alternate domain name like `app.blablabla.cloud` and it serves multiple REST APIs (**Origin Type: API Gateway**) for different services. I wanted to do the same for the websocket API as well

I created a new custom origin for the distribution

- origin domain - `x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com`
- protocol - **HTTPS only**
- HTTPS port - 443
- Minimum origin SSL protocol - TLS v1
- Origin path - *left blank*
- Rest of config - default

After that I created a behaviour and attached this origin

- Path pattern -  `/dev/my-socket/*`
- Compress objects automatically - Yes
- Viewer - **HTTPS only**
- Allowed HTTP methods - GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE
- Restrict viewer access - No
- Cache key and origin requests - Cache policy and origin request policy
  **Cache policy** - CachingDisabled
  **Origin request policy** - created a policy with `Cookies - All`, `Query strings - All` and `Headers - Include the following headers - Sec-WebSocket-Key, Sec-WebSocket-Version, Sec-WebSocket-Protocol, Sec-WebSocket-Accept, Sec-WebSocket-Extensions`
- Rest of config - default

Now i tried to invoke a wss initial call from postman with the url
`wss://app.blablabla.cloud/dev/my-socket/?param1=1&param2=test`

but i get `Status Code: 403 Forbidden` (I'm expecting a `101 Switching Protocols`) and also request headers are

```
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: TVMDG46dqkDM4a7DoM20ZB==
Connection: Upgrade
Upgrade: websocket
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Host: app.blablabla.cloud
```

so it looks like cloudfront is hit just can't get it through. the api gateway dashboard also showed something like
[image]

I don't understand where the issue is. Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Cloudfront distribution in deployed state already?

Comment: @PiyushPatil hi thanks for reply. I can see the Status - ✅Enabled

Comment: I am not 100% sure but Websockets works with custom domains in cloudfront. But again not sure need to test out.

Comment: @PiyushPatil [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-working-with.websockets.html) and [this](https://nickzamosenchuk.medium.com/configure-amazon-cloudfront-cdn-for-websocket-connection-43c44b3f877c) were the only resources i could find myself

Comment: @PiyushPatil hi i found a solution. maybe you can give some insights?

Comment: @PiyushPatil i gave it as an answer. the issue was with the paths. i was wondering if i can use a cloudfront function instead of a lambda@edge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**.
Later tried with cloudfront functions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76958086/13583510) and think it is a better approach

---

the issue was  `API Gateway’s WebSocket API does not support a path parameter in the connection URL. By design (or say it a design oversight), the connection URL path is fixed to the root path / (stage would be prepended when execute-api endpoint is used).` as mentioned in this [medium article](https://medium.com/@lancers/amazon-api-gateway-websocket-api-cloudfront-function-ab304fd95ac3).

In simple terms trying to connect `wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/my-socket/?param1=1&param2=test` will give the same **403 Forbidden** . Only `wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/?param1=1&param2=test` or `wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev?param1=1&param2=test` works.

i.e when i try to connect `wss://app.blablabla.cloud/dev/my-socket/?param1=1&param2=test` it must be trying to connect to `wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev/my-socket/?param1=1&param2=test`

So **approach 1**

- In the behaviour change **Path pattern** - **`/dev`** and bring the precedence down so that the rest of the `dev/stuff/*` are not affected.
- Now I am able to do `wss://app.blablabla.cloud/dev?param1=1&param2=test`

But this is not scalable. What if we need another socket API. we cannot use the same `/dev` for everything.

This leads to better **approach 2**

Using **Lambda@Edge**

- Keep the behaviour as it is with Path pattern - `/dev/my-socket/*`.
- Create a Lambda@Edge and associate it with **Origin request**
- The lambda was simple, just changing the `uri` from `/dev/my-socket/` to `/dev`

```js
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/$/, '');
  return callback(null, request);
};
```

- Now I am able to do `wss://app.blablabla.cloud/dev/my-socket/?param1=1&param2=test` and it will strip the `my-socket` and forward to the correct origin.
- Also the Lambda is invoked only during the connection call. After the handshake is done the Lambda is not involved.
- Also noticed there is a slight latency with this approach compared to using the API gateway url directly