# can i use a cloudfront function to change url in the behaviour path pattern

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

Followup question for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947938/403-forbidden-when-aws-websocket-api-gateway-try-to-serve-through-cloudfront)

I have 2 websocket APIs
**Foo WebSocket API** - `wss://x5g9h3p2rq.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev`
**Bar WebSocket API** - `wss://r2h6k1v8nm.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/dev`

In my distribution, I created 2 origins for these 2 API gateways. Then I created 2 behaviours for those origins with following path patterns
**foo-socket** - `/dev/foo-socket/*`
**bar-socket** - `/dev/bar-socket/*`

My goal is to connect to the respective socket APIs from the browser like
`wss://my-custom-domain/dev/foo-socket/` and `wss://my-custom-domain/dev/bar-socket/`

For this to work I had to associate a Lambda@Edge to the **Origin request** which strips the `/foo-socket/` or `/bar-socket/` from the request URI to just `/dev` since the WebSocket API doesn't accept path parameters other than the stage they provide.

Is this possible with **CloudFront functions** instead since this is just a URL rewrite in a way? I feel like Lambda@Edge adds some latency and it harms the real-time aspects a bit

Help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried Cloudfront function and it worked

- Removed the Lambda@Edge associated with the **Origin Request**
- Created a cloudfront function that looks like

```js
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/\/[^\/]+\/$/, '');
    return request;
}
```

- Here I change the `uri` of the `request` from `/dev/foo-socket/` to `/dev`. Since I'm returning the modified request I associated it with **Viewer Request**. Make sure to publish the function as well.

**NOTE**
cannot use es6 syntax in the function and have to stick with es5 `var`. You will get `503` errors saying and `FunctionExecutionErrors from cloudfront`. Thanks to [this](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/cloudfront-function-encounter-503-error/) (it is not in english tho)